# Test and replace keywords in HTML

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to write two functions:

- first method tests for a match in a string (like *test()*)
- second method replaces keywords

Simply regex (like *\bkeyword\b*) works, but it replaces keywords **inside HTML tags** (e.g class, alt) and **URL anchors**. How should I do this? I can not use JavaScript libraries.

EDIT: I would like replace only first match and only match on exact-matches.

Thanks

Comment: ya..regex works! but you tried something? any code ? that will be great!

Comment: regex parsing HTML -> [TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: If you've some HTML in a string, you better to create a temporary HTMLElement, and set its innerHTML to that string. Then manipulate the textContents of the newly created elements. If you need a HTML as string, get it out of the temporary element, or append the element to the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you use DOM methods you can iterate through the text nodes with a replace function, keeping out of the markup tags-

```
function swapText(node, find, replace){
    var fun= function(n){
        n.data= n.data.replace(find, replace);
    }
    if(node){
        node= node.firstChild;
        while(node!= null){
            if(node.nodeType== 3)fun(node);
            else swapText(node, find, replace);
            node= node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
}
```

swapText(document.body, /e/g, 'E');

Comment: Thanks but it replaces URL anchors. And I would like replace only first match.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an HTML like:

```
var text = '<span class="myclass"> span text </span>';
```

Then you just need to find all the occurrences of the text between html tag and you can replace it by using an anonymous function as a second parameter to replace.

Here i am using `WORD` as a replacement of `span`

```
var result = text.replace(/<[^>]+>|(span)/g, function(p1, p2) { 
     return ((p2==undefined)||p2=='')?p1:"WORD"; 
}); 

console.log(result)
```

Also, check the syntax of replace:

```
newstring = str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[,   flags]);
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Can you show me how you are doing ? May be by adding code in your post or by providing the HTML sample.

Comment: E.g. `var text = '<a href="#" title="a span a">a span a</a> span asd';`
result: `<a href="#" title="a span a">a WORD a</a> WORD asd`

I edited my first post.